# Call Storyboard without Segue

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to do push a ViewController without using Segue, but it is not working.
My button code follow:

```
-(void)consultaButton
{
    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    NSString *viewControllerID = @"Consultas";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    EntradaViewController *controller = (EntradaViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

EntradaViewController / Entrada = origin ViewController
ConsultasViewController / Consultas = target ViewController

I have error:

```
2013-12-12 14:42:51.519 JuntaComercial[14285:70b] -[EntradaViewController consultaButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e51650
```

Could anybody give me a help? I am already using Segue and works fine, but now I need to do the same without Segue. Thanx!!

---

**Update (working code):**

```
-(void)consultaButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    NSString *viewControllerID = @"Consultas";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    EntradaViewController *controller = (EntradaViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
    [controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What's the name of the .storyboard file in your project? That's the name to set for storyboardName.

Comment: Updated... Main.storyboard. But problem persist.

Comment: I think Wain may be onto something. Try changing the method handler to : -(void)consultaButton:(id)sender or, as he suggests, amending the button action code.

Comment: Working Andy... thanks a lot.

One last question... how could I change animation style?

Comment: Before you call presentViewController, set the presentation style. E.g. [controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];

Comment: Thanx again! Final code updated and working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have nothing to do with the storyboard / segue code. Rather, you have a button that you have configured an action on and you have set the action to `consultaButton:`, but the method is actually `consultaButton` (note the lack of a colon because the method has no parameters. So, correct the method signature or the selector you're setting as the button action.

Comment: What I am trying to do is just remove Segue from storyboard. This button only move user from one ViewController to another one. Main-menu to Search-menu.